# Finding Derivatives Using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let's say that $$\ g(x) = \int_{2x}^{3x} \frac{(u^2-1)}{(u^2+1)} du$$

The question asks to find the derivative using FTC. I had two approaches to this problem, but one of them is missing a factor... let me explain:

**My first approach:**

$$ g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \left(\int_{2x}^{3x} \frac{(u^2-1)}{(u^2+1)}\right) = \frac{d}{dx} [ g(3x) - g(2x) ] = f(3x) - f(2x) $$

Plugging in arguments $3x$ and $2x$ in the integrand yielded $\frac{(9x^2-1)}{(9x^2+1)} - \frac{(4x^2-1)}{(4x^2+1)}$ . However, it  is missing a factor of 3 in the first term and a factor of 2 in the second. I'm aware that these values come from the derivatives of the upper and lower limits respectively, but why didn't they show up?

**My second approach was correct, however:**

$$ \int_{2x}^{3x} = \int_0^{3x} - \int_0^{2x}$$
I'll just show the work for $\int_0^{3x}$...

therefore $\frac{d}{dx}3x=3$

$$ g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \left(\int_{2x}^{3x} \frac{(u^2-1)}{(u^2+1)}\right) = g'(x)=\frac{d}{db} \left(\int_{2x}^{3x} \frac{(u^2-1)}{(u^2+1)}\right) \frac{d}{dx}3x  = 3\frac{(u^2-1)}{(u^2+1)}$$

As you can see, in this approach, the factor of 3 shows up because there is $\frac{d}{dx}3x=3$

Where does approach one go wrong?

Comment: If you enclose the upper/lower limits with `{}`, Mathjax will render the properly, i.e. `\int_{2x}^{3x} f(t) dt` will produce $$\int_{2x}^{3x} f(t) dt$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$g(x)=\int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} f(t) dt.$$ By FTC,
$$ g(x) = F(\beta(x)) - F(\alpha(x)) $$ where $F$ is an anti-derivative of $f$. Then by chain rule \begin{align*}g'(x) &= (F(\beta(x)))' - (F(\alpha(x)))' \\
&= f(\beta(x))\beta'(x) - f(\alpha(x))\alpha'(x).
\end{align*}

In your case, $\beta'$ and $\alpha'$ give you the factors $3$ and $2$ respectively.